# Some of the words are crossed-out in Adobe Acrobat Reader Pro if using an Accesibility setting that replaces Documents colors

Tags: pdf, colors, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

As seen below:
[image: Problem]

Those are the settings:
[image: Settings]

The only way I have found to fix this problem is to zoom out/in

Comment: This looks like a rendering issue. With zooming in/out, you do force a redraw. I do have such effects with very complex forms, and have not found any other workaround.

Comment: This problem appears on every page. In my case these effects occur with the simplest of forms - sentences.